# PHP - How to replace all instances of words in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

how can I replace all instances of words using PHP (preferably using regex). This may sound extraordinarily simple, but they have to be words. For instance, if I want to replace the word `foo` in the string `My foot has been hurting all day, get me some food so I can write some foo.` I do not want the words `foot` and `food`'s first three characters to be found because they are a separate entity from the word `foo`.

So the regex must somehow allow the entity being searched to be separate from all others. So if it is surrounded by white-space, begins the string, or ends the string, then it is a word.

I am new to using regular expressions. So your help is much obliged.

Comment: `\Wfoo\W` should match what you want. \W matches any non word character. You might run into an issue if it's at the beginning or end of file, but you can have a separate case for that.

Comment: @RedAlert: bad idea. won't match foo at the very beginning and end positions.

Comment: not to mention the match will contain those extra \W characters, so you have extra work..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Ok, `[\Z\W](foo)[\W\Z]` to account for the edge cases.

Comment: @Red Alert - What is `\Z` meaning in character class?

Comment: @sln: It asserts position at the end of the string.

Comment: If you want to over-complicate it, sure, just do it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Are you saying using word boundaries for the task is over-complicating? Or perhaps I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @Franco Selem - Just a fyi, you accepted an answer that will match `((foo|bar|foo&foo=bar))` as well as foo surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`). It is a zero-length match that matches at a position between a word character (`\w`) and a non-word character (`\W`).

```
$search = 'foo';
echo preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($search).'\b/', '', $str);
```

This will output:

```
My foot has been hurting all day, get me some food so I can write some .
```

Comment: A word boundry isin't appropriate for the OP's definition of separate entity.

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly actually. Works at the beginning/end of strings as well. I really need to learn `regex`. Thanks again.

Comment: @sln: Seeing as the answer is now accepted, I think this is actually an acceptable solution :)

Comment: @FrancoSelem: Happy to have helped. For learning regular expressions, I recommend this website: http://regularexpressions.info - that's what I've been using from the beginning. If you're looking for a book, then try "Mastering Regular Expressions" once you've got a hold of the basic syntax.

Comment: I'm baffled by the downvote; it would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it.

Comment: @FrancoSelem: Glad you found it useful! I'm also learning regular expressions (you're always learning!).