# How to replace any word in a string with regular expressions?

Tags: replace

I have racked my brain trying to come up with a solution to this dilemma.

All I want to do is to replace any occurrence in a text file of numbers of a given value with a specified replacement value.

For example, if I have an ascii elevation raster file that uses zeros (0) to represent raster cells with "no data", and I want to replace those zeros with -9999, I can do that with something like "\b0\b" as the pattern.

However, that pattern will not let me do the opposite ("\b-9999\b") will not work), as in, replace the occurrences of -9999 in a file with zeros (0).

Can anyone solve this puzzle?

Thanks very much.
Clay

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: You're not getting any answers because your question does not follow the guidelines laid out in the link in my comment.

Comment: Well, I think I may have found a solution with this... (?:^|(?<=\s))word(?:(?=\s)|$) ........ 

Thanks to sln here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997453/php-how-to-replace-all-instances-of-words-in-a-string

Comment: Ok. Sorry Toby. I just saw your comment.